# How to determine order number (order No., not quantity) of unique value in vector?

Tags: r

I need to determine order number of unique values in vector x based on unique function. For example:

```
x <- c(3,1,1,2,3,1,2)
y <- unique(x)
y
[1] 3 1 2
```

In result, it must be a vector z like:

```
z (1,2,2,3,1,2,3)
```

where each element of z correspond to order no of element of x value in y (unique function result). 
I.e.: first z element 1 is the order number of value "3" of vector x in y, 
second z element 2 is the order number of value "1" of vector x in y, 
third z element 2 is the order number of value "1" of vector x in y,
fourth z element 3 is the order number of value "2" of vector x in y, etc.

Comment: You can use `match(x, y)`

Comment: Thanks! It's very simple, but very effective!